# Why doesn't my code work when I export non-English text to pdf ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, itext

I am loading URDU text from database and trying to download it in PDF/Word but it doesn't work and give me blank page but for ENGLISH it works fine.

Why doesn't it work for non-english language i.e. as urdu. I am using iText and tried other 3rd party also but not working.

Urdu text loaded from Database column which nvarchar:

```
<p>
    1. <span dir="RTL">میں اس ادارے کی پالیسیوں کی خلاف ورزی نہیں کرے گا</span>.</p>
<p>
    2. <span dir="RTL">میرے فرائض نشان تک ہو گا</span>.</p>
<p>
    3. <span dir="RTL">کوئی خلاف ورزی ادنڈت جانا چاہیئے</span></p>
<p>
    4. <span dir="RTL">میں نے اپنے ملک کے لئے اپنی جان دیتا ہوں گے</span>.</p>
<p>
    5. <span dir="RTL">میں ایک غیر معمولی انداز میں رد عمل کا اظہار تو میری زبان معاف کرنا</span>.</p>
<p>
    6. <span dir="RTL">میں ایسا میرا سب کچھ میرا ادارے اور ملک کی خاطر ہے</span>.</p>
<p>
    7. <span dir="RTL">پاکستان ایک خود مختار ملک ہے اور رہے گی</span>.</p>
<p>
    8. <span dir="RTL">میں مکمل اپنے فرائض کو بھر دوں گا</span></p>
<p>
    9. <span dir="RTL">میں پکڑے گئے تو؛ میں نے آپ کو نہیں پتہ</span>.</p>
<p>
    10. <span dir="RTL">تمام ہے</span>.</p>
```

Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {

                Int64 AppliedWorkID= SharedUtility.DecryptURL(Request.QueryString["AppliedWorkID"].ToString()).ToInt64();

                System.Data.DataTable dt = ClsTender.GetRandomData(AppliedWorkID);

                string Description = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();

                Download(Server.HtmlDecode(Description));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
        }

    }

 private MemoryStream Export(string html)
    {


        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);


        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        // and directs a XML-stream to a file
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);

        // step 3: we create a worker parse the document
        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

        // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
        document.Open();
        worker.StartDocument();

        // step 5: parse the html into the document
        worker.Parse(reader);

        // step 6: close the document and the worker
        worker.EndDocument();
        worker.Close();
        document.Close();


        return msOutput;
    }

    public void Download(string html)
    {

            try
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = Export(html); // returns a memory stream object
                byte[] bytesInStream = memStream.ToArray();
                Response.Clear();

                string FileName = "TestPDF.pdf";
                FileName = FileName.Replace(",", "");

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.Headers.Remove("content-disposition");
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + "\"");

                Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
                Response.End();
                Response.Flush();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }

            //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Print", "javascript:window.print();", true);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `HTMLWorker`. It is obsolete and deprecated. Use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: Secondly, you do not embed the font containing the urdu-glyphs, which is why you're getting a blank page instead of text. Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-different-languages